# Monotouch UISplitViewController hide master view like Mail app

Tags: xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app I want to show Master view in both landscape and portrait modes and it works fine with any special code.

But I want to be able to hide/show master view with left/right gestures, similar to Mail app.

Is there a simple way of enabling this or do I need to write my own gesture recognition?

By the way, if I disable master view in ShouldHideViewController delegate then gestures works automatically, but I don't want master view to be hidden by default.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [MTSplitViewController](https://github.com/Krumelur/MTSplitViewController) instead.  It is a port of the excellent [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I did for now and it works, but has a few issues. One of them is that master view always deselects current selected item and I want it to stay - my code works fine with UISplitViewController.

Comment: After playing a little bit I think this is the best solution for now.